# Weird behavior in tensorflow if inputs is a dictionary

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

Tensorflow version: 2.1

OS - ubuntu 20.04

If we use the `name` parameter while creating an 'Input` layer then we can feed the inputs to the model as a dictionary. One would expect the dictionary input to actually map key: value pairs properly but i fear that is not happening.  Below is the minimum reproducible code to have a peek into the issue:

```
import tensorflow as tf
class IL(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
    def call(self,inputs,training=True):
        return inputs

il = IL()
aa = tf.keras.Input((2,), name='a')
bb = tf.keras.Input((2,), name='b')
cc = tf.keras.Input((2,), name='c')
ix1 = {'pq':cc,'mn':aa,'yz':bb}
out1 = il(ix1)
model = tf.keras.Model(ix1, [out1])
x1 = {'1': np.arange(0,2,dtype=np.float32).reshape(-1,2),\
      '3': np.arange(10,12,dtype=np.float32).reshape(-1,2),
      'a': np.arange(20,22,dtype=np.float32).reshape(-1,2)}
y_pred = model(x1,training=True)
```

Expected behavior:
x1 gets mapped to corresponding keys. i dont know if those keys are supposed to be layer names or input dict given to model `ix1`.

Question 1: Can you clarify what the dictionary keys in inputs are to be for?

Current behavior:
The concept of dictionary is tossed out completely. What is happening is `x1` will get sorted on keys and be fed to model in order as if `1x1` was sorted as well. Meaning, in the above use-case 'mn' ('a' according to layer name) will map to `1` in `x1`, `pq` to `3` and `yz` to `a`. What is going on here? im looking for a little insight into how things work with tensorflow. Right now it seems as much of a sticks and stones contraption as tensorflow 1 was which, breaks my heart

Answer (score 0):

The input data `x1`'s keys and `ix1`'s keys are both sorted before feeding to the model. Therefore, they are matched with each other in sorted order.

Take examples in your case, if we change `x1` keys to `['5', '3', '2']` and `ix1` to `['1', '2', '3']`, then they will be combined with each other in reverse sequence.

As far as I concerned that, if we defined `ix1` and `x1` with the same keys, it will be fine.

Below is my test code:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers
import numpy as np

class IL(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
    def call(self,inputs,training=True):
        return inputs

il = IL()
aa = tf.keras.Input((2,), name='a')
bb = tf.keras.Input((2,), name='b')
cc = tf.keras.Input((2,), name='c')
ix1 = {'1':cc,'2':aa,'3':bb}
out1 = il(ix1)
model = tf.keras.Model(ix1, [out1])
x1 = {'5': np.arange(0,2,dtype=np.float32).reshape(-1,2),\
      '3': np.arange(10,12,dtype=np.float32).reshape(-1,2),
      '1': np.arange(20,22,dtype=np.float32).reshape(-1,2)}
y_pred = model(x1,training=True)
print(y_pred)
```

The output:

```sh
[{'1': <tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 2), dtype=float32, numpy=array([[20., 21.]], dtype=float32)>,
  '2': <tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 2), dtype=float32, numpy=array([[10., 11.]], dtype=float32)>,
  '3': <tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 2), dtype=float32, numpy=array([[0., 1.]], dtype=float32)>}]
```

Play coding~

Comment: but isnt the point of giving your api the capability to consume dictionary completely forfeited by this behavior. Should the behavior not be to throw an error if the key is not found in the input dictionary. You may or may not be allowed to have extra kay:value pairs in the input dictionaty but you shouldnt be allowed to not have an input key:value pair availabel that the model expects. It seems there is no point of keys at all but they serve as a sorting index to the collection and then one-to-one mapping follows.